Why I get different shap values according to the different order of inputs by using function shap.Explainer?
I trained a two-classification model and wanted to use shap.Explainer to analyze feature contribution.
The code was:
def f(x):
    return model.predict_proba(x)[:, 1]

X100 = shap.utils.sample(X_train, 100)

explainer = shap.Explainer(f, X100, seed=2023)
shap_values = explainer(data.iloc[[0,1,2,3], :])

The results of shap_values.values was:




Feature 1
...




sample 0
-0.009703
...


sample 1
-0.009297
...


sample 2
-0.007699
...


sample 3
0.032624
...



But when the input order changed:
def f(x):
    return model.predict_proba(x)[:, 1]

X100 = shap.utils.sample(X_train, 100)

explainer = shap.Explainer(f, X100, seed=2023)
shap_values = explainer(data.iloc[[1,0,2,3], :])

the results were changed for sample 0 and sample 1:




Feature 1
...




sample 1
-0.010012
...


sample 0
-0.008277
...


sample 2
-0.007699
...


sample 3
0.032624
...



I have no idea about the difference.

The shap.Explainer in auto algorithm selected shap.PermutationExplainer by itself. The class shap.PermutationExplainer sets the seed in __init__, but it calls np.random.shuffle in one of the functions in this class for each sample repeatedly. So the sample order may influence the final results
